# Insertar datos en una Tabla Temporal desde un Stored

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo un stored procedure llamado **Sp_Ejecucion** dentro de el creo una tabla temporal con la siguiente estructura.:

```
CREATE TABLE #CambioResult (FOL INT IDENTITY, RESULT INT)
```

y despues de eso mando a ejecutar otro Sp de la siguiente manera

```
BEGIN TRAN T1
    DECLARE @vnCambiaRollTurnoResult    INT = 0,
            @vnReacomodoMarcajesResult  INT = 0,
            @Result                     INT = 0

    BEGIN TRY
        exec nsp_Exec                   @nClaEmp        = @pnClaEmpresa, 
                                        @nClaTrab       = @pnClaTrab, 
                                        
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        GOTO RETURN_ERROR
    END CATCH
```

Y el dentro del segundo stored quiero insertar datos a la tabla creada en el primer stored, ¿Como le puedo hacer? lo que he intendado es lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CambioResult')
    select @Error
```

pero marca error en esta parte **OBJECT_ID**

Comment: Simplemente haz `INSERT INTO #CambioResult (RESULT ) VALUES (@Error)`.

Answer (score 0):

El ámbito de la tabla temporal creada, se mantiene en la ejecución del segundo procedimiento.

**Segundo procedimiento**

```
Create procedure nsp_exec (@nClaEmpresa int, @nClaTrab int)
as
BEGIN
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#cambioResult') IS NOT NULL
    begin
        Insert into #cambioResult (result)
        SELECT @nClaEmpresa;
    end
End
GO
```

**Primer procedimiento** Tiene un par de pequeñas variantes con el código que has expuesto.

```
Create procedure spEjecucion @param1 int
As
CREATE TABLE #CambioResult (FOL INT IDENTITY, RESULT INT);
BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @vnCambiaRollTurnoResult    INT = 0,
            @vnReacomodoMarcajesResult  INT = 0,
            @Result                     INT = 0;


    BEGIN TRY
        exec nsp_Exec @param1,100;
                                        
    SELECT * FROM #CambioResult;
COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       if @@TRANCOUNT>0
        rollback tran
    END CATCH
GO
```

Ahora al ejecutar el procedimiento exterior, con un parámetro este se envía al procedimiento interior y es quien realiza la inserción en la tabla temporal. La salida se retorna en el procedimiento exterior.

```
EXEC spEjecucion 500;
```

[image: Result]

**Posibles puntos de mejora adicionales**:

No deberías de utilizar este tipo de tablas temporales con ejecuciones internas porque son difíciles de mantener.

No deberías de usar GOTO

Si abres una transacción deberías realizar un COMMIT cuando sea el caso y un ROLLBACK cuando esté abierta.

**Posibles soluciones**
Una estrategia interesante es utilizar **Tipos** como estructuras para mover información.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].cambioResult AS TABLE(
          FOL INT IDENTITY
        , RESULT INT);
GO
```

Creamos de nuevo el segundo procedimiento:

```
Create or alter procedure dbo.nsp_exec (
      @nClaEmpresa int
    , @nClaTrab int
    , @varTable as dbo.cambioResult readonly
    )
as
BEGIN
        -- Leo los datos en el procedimiento interior
        Select * from @varTable

End
GO
```

Este recoge un parámetro de tipo `dbo.cambioResult`, del cual podemos leer información. No guardar.

Primer procedure

```
Create or alter procedure dbo.spEjecucion @param1 int
As
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
    
    DECLARE @vnCambiaRollTurnoResult    INT = 0,
            @vnReacomodoMarcajesResult  INT = 0,
            @Result                     INT = 0;

    -- Inserto en el tipo definido en el procedimiento exterior
    DECLARE @miVar as dbo.cambioResult;
    Insert into @miVar (result)
    Values (@Param1);

    -- llamo al procedimiento interior
    exec dbo.nsp_Exec @param1,100, @miVar ;
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    if @@TRANCOUNT>0
        Rollback Tran
END CATCH
GO
```

Ahora trabajo en el primer procedimiento lo que necesite y se lo paso al segundo que hará lo que tenga que hacer, porque ya dispone de los datos.

[image: Result2]

Si necesitas recuperar en el procedure exterior, lo que has hecho en el interior.

[Recuperar información desde procedures](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/08/27/insert-temp-table-result-procedure/)